# How do I remove or cut some number in php

Tags: php

Let's say I have this number `0601811002` and I want cut the number.

Example :-

I want remove 5 chars

`0601811002`and will be `06018`

If I want remove 4 chars

`0601811002`and will be `060181`

If I want remove 7 chars

`0601811002`and will be `060`

Let me know

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo substr("0601811002", 0, -5);
```

will cut off last five characters

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/822fc.php

result: 06018

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: This is the way, the negative number being the amount of characters to remove from the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = substr("0601811002", 0, -4);
```

cuts 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is `substr`:

is http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

More precisely (based on your examples):

```
<?php
    $cut_5_chars = substr("0601811002", 0, -5);
    $cut_4_chars = substr("0601811002", 0, -4);
    $cut_7_chars = substr("0601811002", 0, -7);
?>
```

Try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '0601811002';
$str = substr($str, 0, -4); // Chop 4 characters off of string
echo $str;                          // 060181
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's real number(not quoted by ' or "), you can cut it in math way.

```
<?php
    $str = 601811002;
    $str_1 = floor($str/100000);  //cut last 5 numbers
    echo $str_1;                  //6081

    $str_2 = floor($str%100000);  //retains last 5 numbers
    echo $str_2;                  //11002
?>
```